# inotify not releasing watch handles on close() / termination

Tags: kernel, inotify

I'm trying to use inotify to monitor resources used by a container and have come across what looks like a bug. I'm using the following code to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int fd;
  int wd;
  int error;
  fd = inotify_init();
  if (fd >= 0) {
    printf("inotify_init: success fd=[%d]\n", fd);

    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/tmp", IN_ALL_EVENTS);
    if (wd >= 0) {
      printf("inotify_add_watch: success fd=[%d] wd=[%d]\n", fd, wd);
    }

    if (inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd) >= 0) {
      printf("inotify_rm_watch: success fd=[%d] wd=[%d]\n", fd, wd);
    } else {
      printf("inotify_rm_watch: error fd=[%d] wd=[%d] errno=[%d]\n", fd, wd,     errno);
    }

    error = close(fd);
    if (error) {
      printf("close(fd) error: %d\n", error);
    } else {
      printf("close(fd) success fd=[%d] error=[%d]\n", fd, error);
    }
  } else {
    printf("inotify_init failed: %d\n", fd);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This should add a watch on `/tmp`, immediately remove it and then close the inotify instance.

If I run this on my laptop (Arch Linux, using a 3.7.5 kernel) then everything works as expected: `for i in $(seq 1 200); do ./a.out; done` will happily add and remove watches as long as I want. Likewise on an old Ubuntu 10.04 machine using the 2.6.32 kernel.

However, on an Ubuntu 12.04 box with a 3.2.0 kernel, issuing the same command will show a run of `n` successful runs and then immediately start failing, where `n` is equal to /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances: in other words, the instances aren't being closed properly. The inotify file descriptors are being removed successfully, which leads me to assume that there's some sort of regression in the inotify code.

Has anybody else run across this issue, or is able to reproduce it? I haven't spotted anything on the Internet about this problem, but I can't think of what else could likely be causing this.